# decoding JSON in view sent from django app

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

I have a django app with a web page POST-ing a JSON object created like this:

```
var content = '{ "EnergylinxTariffMenu" : [' +
     '{ "FuelPage":"dual" , "DualMenu":"electric",' +
     '  "SupplierName":"npower", "MeterType": "",' +
     '  "TestLive":"test"} ]}';
document.mainform.elements['json_content'].value = JSON.parse(content);
```

In my view I want to process this:

```
import json
jdata = json.loads(request.POST['json_content'])
```

But that fails with:

```
*** ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

What is the proper way to decode this?

This is django 1.7 with python 3.4

Comment: Why are you first building a JSON string by hand and then parsing it back to an actual object? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: The requirement from my client is to provide a view that takes JSON inputs and I am trying to write something to develop and test that with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `JSON.parse` in the Javascript is not only pointless, it is what is breaking your test. What you want in the field value is the raw JSON string, ie the direct value of `content`: if you call JSON.parse first, it will be converted to a JS object, and the string value of that is just `[object Object]` - hence your error.

Really, what you want to do is to build up an object in JS, and dump that to the element using `JSON.stringify`:

```
var content = { EnergylinxTariffMenu : [
     { "FuelPage":"dual" , "DualMenu":"electric",
       "SupplierName":"npower", "MeterType": "",
       "TestLive":"test"} ]};
document.mainform.elements['json_content'].value = JSON.stringify(content);
```

Comment: OK, thanks much. I thought I had to call JSON.parse to make it into JSON. I see now that I do not have to do that.

Comment: But now in my view I'm getting a string not a list or dict.

Comment: Well you still need to call `json.loads` in Python.

Comment: Yes, I am and what I get from that is a string:

(Pdb) type(json.loads(request.POST['json_content']))
<class 'str'>

Comment: Show your updated JS code. Are you perhaps now calling `stringify` on your original string, rather than a JS object as I recommended?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. It was not clear to me from your answer that I had to do that. Thanks again.